# How can I change the document title in word by typing it into a field in the document?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I am making a template and it has a field named Title. I want that when the user writes the title it automatically changes the document title so I can have a constant updated title in the header. I cannot use VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a mapped content control to insert a field into a document that will update the title document property when changed. You can read up on mapped content controls [here](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html).

To insert a content control mapped to the title document property in Microsoft Word 2007 and up, navigate to `Insert` on the ribbon, Click `Quick Parts` followed by `Document Properties` and choose `Title`.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that enables the user to write the title as part of the text in the document and the text he introduces becomes the document title. I don't intend to have a field that shows the updated title but instead it's able to change it according user input.

Comment: @doubter, Yes a mapped content control like described above will update the document title when the user types into it. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Click wherever you want eventually want to manually type the title.

1. Click **Developer tab**

   *(If you don't have the Developer Tab, click File > Options > Customize Ribbon, then under Main Tabs select the Developer check box.)*
2. Click **XML Mapping Pane**
3. From the drop-down, select the Custom XML Part that ends in /core-properties.
4. Right-click **Title**, then click **Insert Content Control** from the popup menu, then **Plain Text** (or whatever).

It will auto-populate with whatever the Document Title currently is, but it's now a "two-way street" -- if you type in there, it updates the actual Document Title.

To have that property echoed elsewhere,

1. Click the cursor wherever you want it to go
2. Select **Insert** > **Quick Parts** > **Document Property** > **Title**